# Bug in android studio? Can't access protected member in sub-class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Look, PlanetShape extends Shape!
[image: Look, PlanetShape extends Shape!]
And yet it says isOverlapMethodLevel have protected access in Shape!
[image: And yet it says isOverlapMethodLevel have protected access in Shape!]

Did I just discovered a bug in android studio? Or is it something else?

Comment: what is your project structure?

Comment: PlanetShape and Shape are in the same package. Does the structure matter? i thought sub class can access super class protected member no matter what.

Comment: yes, it matters

Comment: Please consider posting *actual code as text* rather than linking to images - It isn't possible for anyone to check, run or cut-and-paste from an image, and it doesn't display readably on many displays such as mobile. Furthermore images often end up as broken links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages differ in your class hierarachy - specifically your `PlanetShape` class is in a different package to the classes it extends.

Directly from [Java documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) (emphasis mine)

> The **protected** modifier specifies that the member *can only be accessed*
>   *within its own package* (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

Clearly the "*by a subclass of its class in another package*" seems to be the cause of some confusion and I agree that the wording is rather ambiguous.

Basically, what they're ***trying to say*** is you can do this:

```
public class PlanetShape extends Shape {
    aMethod() {
        // call the protected method declared in the Super class (ok)
        doProtectedMethodOfShape();
    }    
}
```

But ***not*** this:

```
public class PlanetShape extends Shape {
    aMethod() {
        Shape s = new Shape();
        s.doProtectedMethodOfShape(); // error here
    }    
}
```

In the second example, you get an error because you're not accessing a protected method *via inheritance*, you're just trying to access a protected member function from an instance in another package.

Comment: and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

Isn't PlanetShape a subclass of Shape?

Comment: @ShuangLi I have edited to try and clarify. I agree that the wording in the docs is ambiguous - but this is definitely *not* an android studio bug, it is expected behaviour of the `protected` modifier.

Comment: Ok, this is still confusing to me but i'll make isOverlapMethodLevel public. It is final anyway. thanks!

Comment: I think what I am confusing with is that private member can be accessed from another instance. In that case which instance it is doesn't matter, but in this case it does.